# Access Files On Shared Drives Without Mapping

Tags: java, c#

I have written a program that can go out and check file version info for a particular file. This needs to happen on a large scale basis, something like 8000 computers or so. The way I've been doing it up until now is mapping the shared path I need to a drive letter, checking the required file, and then unmapping the drive. Each one of these shared areas requires the same username and password to be entered for security purposes. As you would imagine, mapping and unmapping the drive in order to check file version info slows my program down. So, I was wondering, is there any special way that is more efficient, and quicker to do this?

Keep in mind, this does have to go across a network, so I don't think it will ever be lightning fast but if someone could provide some design pointers for a better solution I would be all ears.

Thanks and I appreciate it! Or if anyone has heard of libraries which simply this process that would be great if you could share them. At the moment this is written in C#, soon to be re-written in Java.